# AdsOpenObject() fails for tree in trusted forest

Tags: active-directory

Setup is as follows

Forest A

Forest B(trust between A and B is present)

-Separate tree domain(Bt) in forest B

In my application, I am using AdsOpenObject(path, username, password,...) to get list of all groups.
When I am calling it by setting "path" to local domain or forest(A) it works fine.
It also works fine for trusted forest(B).
But when I call AdsOpenObject() for path of separate tree in trusted forest(Bt) it is failing with error as "domain not found".
I am able to logon(LogonUser) using user of that tree domain(Bt).

Anybody have any idea about this behaviour
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you connect to domain bt using serverless binding? E. g. Ldap://dc=bt,dc=com? If so, replace it with the following: ldap://bt.com/dc=bt,dc=com

Comment: I can only use serverless binding because of application limitation(I dont always know name of server). Code is ,  hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://DC=adtree, DC=com",
      L"adtree\\Administrator",
      L"Password",
      ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION,
      IID_IDirectorySearch,
      (void **)&pDirectorySearcher);
This works fine for trusted forest but not for tree in trusted forest

Comment: I will also try your suggestion, but even if it works I can not implement it in my application.

Comment: I am able to see the list of groups after adding server name to path.
But I dont how to get servername of AD of tree in separate forest programatically

Comment: I tried with  ldap://bt.com/dc=bt,dc=com, but its not working

Comment: So, from your comments I cannot understand if the solution works or not. Why does serverless binding used? It requires domain distinguished name. The common scenario is to provide Fqdn domain name to the program and the program itself queries dn in rootdse ad partition

Comment: And what the input data for the program is? For example, forest root domain is provided. The forest structure is unknown. The program has to find and query all child domains, other forest trees, trusted domains and their forest trees. Or the structure is known and you just need to connect to 1 domain in forest a and two domains in forest b

Comment: 1) My application is listing all groups(from all domains in current forest and from domain of loggedin user from tree domain from trusted forest)

2) Now i dont know the name of server on which domain controller of tree domain from trusted forest is present

Now about the solution,

1) I tried with ldap://bt.com/dc=bt,dc=com, but its not working


2) Note : I am able to see the list of groups after adding server name to path. But I dont how to get servername of AD of tree in separate forest programatically

Comment: Do you get the same error then you bind to bt.com? Can you connect to this domain using aduc/ldp.exe/adsiedit from the machine, where  your program executes? Can you ping bt.com domain from this machine? P.S. To get domain controllers you can query configuration partition of the trusted forest root domain,  e.g. cn=server,cn=servers,cn=sitename,cn=sites,cn=configuration,dc=...